# Problems playing videos in Leanback example

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, leanback

I am trying to play my own videos in Android Leanback example (https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) putting in PlaybackFragment.java line 178, in prepareMediaForPlaying(Uri.parse(...)) my own mp4 url and it doesn't work. I have an Source error and the log said that it couldn't access to this url. I know that the url that I am trying works properly, because I put it in a browser and it plays.

Could you help me please?

Comment: you can used exoplayer to play video

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand which type of video are you going to play! HLS, DASH, MPEG or of which format!
after you got a basic understanding on them, look for exoplayer supporting video formats, then implement your desired one